# What file types are supported by react-dropzone?

Tags: reactjs, react-dropzone

I checked the documentation to see what are the file types this library support.

> A  file extension starting with the STOP character (U+002E). (e.g. .jpg, .png, .doc).

But, what is the file extension starting with the stop char?

Answer (score 0):

It's a fullstop "."

As per the examples you provided stop char is stop character.

Comment: so does it mean any file type with `.` will be accepted and able to be uploaded?

Comment: Think about what it is doing? Does it have to process a file type? Or simply take a file